# Can't mount second hdd due to error /dev/mapper/backup--mint--vg-root: can't read superblock

Tags: mount, lvm, luks, fsck

I'm trying to mount a second hdd. I don't know where I'm going wrong. First, I set up a partition with cryptsetup:

```
sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdb5 backup
sudo vgdisplay
```

I got two identical vg names, according to this advice https://askubuntu.com/questions/110226/how-do-you-mount-a-lvm-patition-that-has-the-same-vg-name-as-my-current-partitio
I renamed the one that is my backup source:

```
vgrename M06MX4-J1Uc-ezEw-H0VQ-lXSQ-alDr-wTn623 backup-mint-vg
```

`sudo lvscan` shows an inactive `backup-mint-vg` that became active after `sudo vgchange -ay`, but I can't mount it:

```
sudo mount /dev/backup-mint-vg/root sdb5
```

And:

```
sudo mount /dev/dm-4 sdb5
mount: /dev/mapper/backup--mint--vg-root: can't read superblock
```

There are many errors:

```
$ sudo pvdisplay 
  /dev/mapper/backup: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: errors/IO
  /dev/mapper/backup: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 119774576640:
  [skip next 30 lines of same errors]
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/backup
  VG Name               backup-mint-vg
  PV Size               111,55 GiB / not usable 2,00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              28556
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          28556
  PV UUID               EQRjEE-D5jq-RVyo-bhUC-1Fp1-udWK-KG7Mdb

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt
  VG Name               mint-vg
  PV Size               148,57 GiB / not usable 3,00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              38033
  Free PE               6
  Allocated PE          38027
  PV UUID               Z3hkoa-ACP3-GqDb-qvTu-gZqL-S90M-cWQ0sW
```

How can I correct these issues? 
I think I should `fsck -cck /dev/backup-mint-vg/root` somehow?

UPD1: the Q concerns the running system
`sudo uname  -srvmpio
Linux 4.15.0-43-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 7 13:30:54 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`
`lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Release:    18.3
Codename:   sylvia`

UPD2  I managed to solve problem with help of livecd (mint install media)
 after renaming operation i still needed the `fsck -cck` of renamed volume. that was not possible from running system but from livecd

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: linuxmint 18.03 based on UBUNTU XENIAL 16.04

Comment: Mint is off topic here. Only official versions of Ubuntu family of distributions are supported. See the site help page for more information about which questions are not allowed.

Comment: I reproduced the matter of question with fresh ubuntu xenial 16.04 install, just the same problem. UPD: I manged to solve problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect Ubuntu version. Then write your own answer on how you solved the problem. Finally accept your answer as correct. If the problem was caused by your own mistake and the answer is unlikely to help others, then please delete the question.